# Vertically partition an RDD and write to separate locations

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In spark 1.5+ how can I write each column of an "n"-tuple RDD to different locations?

For example if I had a `RDD[(String, String)]` I would like the first column to be written to `s3://bucket/first-col` and the second to `s3://bucket/second-col`

I could do the following

```
 val pairRDD: RDD[(String, String)]
 val cachedRDD = pairRDD.cache()
 cachedRDD.map(_._1).saveAsTextFile("s3://bucket/first-col")
 cachedRDD.map(_._2).saveAsTextFile("s3://bucket/second-col")
```

But is far from ideal since I need a two-pass over the RDD.

Comment: If you were working solely with `Tuple2`'s then you could use `pairRDD.keys` and `pairRDD.values`

Answer (score 1):

One way you could you can go about doing this is by converting the tuples into lists and then use map to create a list of RDDs and perform a save on each as follows:

```
val fileNames:List[String] 
val input:RDD[(String, String...)] //could be a tuple of any size
val columnIDs = (1 to numCols)
val unzippedValues = input.map(_.productIterator.toList).persist() //converts tuple into list
val columnRDDs = columnIDs.map( a => unzippedValues.map(_(a)))
columnRDDs.zip(fileNames)foreach{case(b,fName) => b.saveAsTextFile(fName)}
```